# GNU GMP mpz_powm() without mod

Tags: math, gnu, gmp

[GNU GMP](http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Exponentiation.html#Integer-Exponentiation) provides a functions called `mpz_powm(rop, base, exp, mod)` which allows me to power a very big integer value by another very big integer value. The function also forces me to modulate the result by the 4th parameter. That's what the "m" stands for in `mpz_powm`. The reason why there isn't a function without a mod parameter could be to avoid very big results which may fill up your whole memory like: `2^(2^64)`. I'd like to know if there is a possibility anyway to use that function without specifying a mod parameter by just taking the risk to reach your memory limit.

Comment: No, there isn't. Unless `base` is one of `-1,0,1`, if the exponent doesn't fit in an `unsigned long int` - when you could use `mpz_pow_ui` - the power without modulo couldn't be computed since it would need too many limbs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `mpz_pow_ui ()`. If the argument you wish to pass does not fit in a single word then the result wouldn't fit in memory anyway (except for the trivial cases):

```
void mpz_pow_ui (mpz_t ROP, mpz_t BASE, unsigned long int EXP)
```

Comment: I know that function. But I'd like my exp to be a `mpz_t` too. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something :/

Comment: @arminb Either you are in a trivial case (0, 1, -1), or you can convert your `mpz_t` without loss to an `unsigned long int`, or the result of the function you wish, `mpz_pow(…, …, exp);` is “Out of memory”.

Comment: Ah, okay now I get it. Because size of `unsigned long int` is 64 bits (in my case) the result wouldn't fit into memory if exp parameter is > 0xffffffffffffffff.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modulate your answer, you'll need to use `mpz_pow_ui`. However, because exponentiating with a large `mpz_t` will create an integer that won't fit into memory, the exponent has to be an `unsigned long int`.

So just convert your exponent, and then use the function:

`mpz_pow_ui (rop, base, mpz_get_ui(exp))`

However, if your exponent is larger than ULONG_MAX, (typically 2^32-1), you'll get overflow errors.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.